# Alter Table Add Column - Record too large error VBA SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to add a column to an existing Access 2007 database and name it the value in a predetermined cell ("B3" in this case).

```
Sub InsertField()

Dim nfield As String, ntable As String, wsr As Worksheet, objAccess As   Object

Set wsr = Sheets("Sheet1")

wsr.Select
ntable = "MyTable"
nfield = wsr.Range("B3").Value

Set objAccess = New Access.Application
   ' open access database
  Call objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase( _
  "C:\Users\user\Desktop\MyDatabase.accdb")
  ' add field
  objAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute ("ALTER TABLE " + ntable + " ADD COLUMN " + nfield + " CHAR")

End Sub
```

This code works on an empty test Access database, but when I run it on my production database (~330MB) I get the following error on the "ALTER TABLE" line:

```
Run-time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Record is too large.
```

References are identical between the databases.

This code worked on the production database for a time so I feel like I hit some limit, but I cannot find any limit in the specifications that I meet or exceed.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if you have UnicodeCompression turned on for the table? With that property on there is a limit of 4000 bytes per row on the table. Adding that `CHAR` column might extend an existing row past that limit, while in any empty database none of the rows will have gone over that limit.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the datatype from CHAR to TEXT and it works now. I also tried you solution with the original code and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your help!